# NetLogo Dimensions In Space

Tags: netlogo

1.How does the coordinate system in NetLogo shape in terms of "cms" as horizontal coordinate(cm) and vertical coordinate(cm)?(The settings tab sure does give in pixels but I unfortunately don't know the conversion between pixels and cms)

2.How does turtle size correlate with or is specified in pixels?

***UPDATE.***

Is there any possible way given my screen resolution I can accomplish the above conversion?
I found some links http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html claiming to do the above I don't know regarding their crediblity

Comment: The site you linked assumes a [pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) of 96 PPI (pixels per inch). Pixel density depends on both screen resolution _and_ physical size. If you find out what the density is for your screen, sure, you can calculate a turtle size in cm; but it would only be valid on that screen and those of the same density. I'm not sure how useful that can really be...

Comment: Why do you want to know? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.How does the coordinate system in Netlogo shape in terms of "cms" as horizontal coordinate(cm) and vertical coordinate(cm)?(The settings tab sure does give in pixels but I unfortunately don't know the conversion between pixels and cms)

It doesn't. There is no general conversion between pixels and centimeters, nor should there be. The physical size of a pixel depends on your screen size and resolution. For the purpose of a model, you can always *decide* that, e.g., 10 pixels *represent* 1cm, but this would have no correlation to actual physical size on screen.

> 2.How does turtle size correlate with or is specified in pixels?

Ah! This one actually has an answer: a turtle of [`size`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#size) 1.0 is the same size as a patch, and [`patch-size`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-size) gives you the size of a patch in pixels. The size of a turtle in pixels is thus `size * patch-size`. Note, however, that this is the size of the side of the square occupied by the turtle; not the actual area of the shape displayed on the screen.

Comment: Pleaase check the above update. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possible way given my screen resolution I can accomplish the above conversion?

This depends not only on the resolution of the monitor, but the monitor itself. For instance, if your monitor is 1440x900 and you project up on a screen, or plug into an external monitor that scales the output, obviously the pixels-per-cm is going change dramatically, even though the resolution stays the same. Even within the same monitor, this can change. For instance, many modern laptops (notably macbook pros) have so called hi-dpi screens with huge resolutions. Applications on the screens can be run in scaled or non-scaled formats, which completely changes the pixels-per-cm (e.g. NetLogo 5.0.5 ran in scaled-mode on OS X, but 5.1 runs in non-scaled-mode; you'll notice that the text on retina screens looks considerably sharper and less pixelated). Even just in netlogo, you can zoom in and out, which changes the scale of all the elements (see the zoom menu).

So, the only way to determine the pixels-per-cm is for a specific application on a specific monitor running under a specific resolution with specific settings. In that case, your best bet for measuring the size of patches and turtles is probably a ruler. You can probably find some applications that give you a "screen ruler", but the only trustworthy ones I'm aware give the answer in pixels, and I probably wouldn't trust anything that claims to give cm.

I think you're having trouble getting the answer you want here because, in some sense, the question doesn't really make sense. The measurement of patches in cm can always be changed at will and will always change depending on environment. So perhaps the best answer to your first question is "whatever you want it to be".